# Android Studio Javamail with own domain

Tags: android, android-studio, email

I have a problem. I want to send emails after registering and I have an own domain. But this code only works for gmail accounts (It works when I put in a gmail address).
Do you have any ideas

```
    loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myEmail = "info@vitaforis.com";
            String emailPassword = "11111";

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //"smtp.vitaforis.com" doesnt work either
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(myEmail, emailPassword);
                }
            });

            try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myEmail));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email.getText().toString().trim()));
                message.setSubject("Thank you for registering");
                message.setText("Welcome");
                new SendMail().execute(message);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

private class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Message, String, String>{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Message... messages) {

        try {
            Transport.send(messages[0]);
            return "success";
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (s.equals("success")) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "It worked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (s.equals("error")) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```